# Redux-thunk with redux-form - not dispatching

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form

Long post below, but not complicated!
I have setup my form:

**NewCommentForm Component**

```
class NewCommentForm extends Component {
    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field component="input" type="text" name="title"/>
                <Field component="textarea" type="text" name="content"/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({})
// Actions are imported as 'import * as action from '../actions/comments'
NewCommentForm = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(NewCommentForm)

NewCommentForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'newComment',
    onSubmit: actions.postComment // This is the problem!
})(NewCommentForm);
```

**RemoteSubmitButton Component**

```
class RemoteSubmitButton extends Component {
    render() {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        return (
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => dispatch(submit('newComment'))}>Submit</button>
      )
    }
}
RemoteSubmitButton = connect()(RemoteSubmitButton);
```

Everything wrapped in **NewComment Component**:

```
class NewComment extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div className="new-comment">
                    <NewCommentForm />
                    <RemoteSubmitButton />
                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is with the `postComment` function:

```
export const postComment = (comment) => {
    console.log("Post comment - first;") // THIS ONE GETS CALLED
    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log("Post comment - second"); // THIS ONE IS NEVER CALLED
        return api.postComment(comment).then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS',
                response
            });
        });
    }
}
```

that gets its `api.postComment` from another file:

```
export const postComment = (comment) => {
    return axios.post(post_comment_url, {
        comment
    }).then(response => {
        return response;
    });
}
```

I have `redux-thunk` setup in my store:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const configureStore = (railsProps) => {
    const middlewares = [thunk];
  const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    railsProps,
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
  );
  return store;
};
```

Why after submitting the form using the `RemoteSubmitButton` the second part of the `postComment` function is never called? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are trying to use the action that is not connected with the `react-redux` `connect`. You have to use it inside the component that is connected to the redux.

Comment: I wish that was the case. But adding the catch changes nothing at all. No log is displayed and still I only get `Post comment - first` messege

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I passed `this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.postComment)` to the form `onSubmit` but then an error appeared: `You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop`.

Comment: I identified your problem, but now you have to learn how you can do this using react-form reading the docs. I think [this link](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/) might help you.

Comment: But the thing is that the `postComment` function is connected using redux `connect`.

Comment: `action.postComment` is not connected, `this.props.postComment` is connected.

Comment: That is what I wrote as my second comment to you answer.
I finally found out how to do it - I had to pass `onSubmit` to `NewCommentForm` like: `<NewCommentForm onSubmit={this.props.postComment} />`.